# Evaluate $\iint { \sqrt{\left| y-{ x }^{ 2 } \right|}\, dx\,dy } $ over a rectangle

Tags: calculus, integration, area

**Question:** 
I want to evaluate $\iint_R {\sqrt{ \left| y-{ x }^{ 2 } \right|}\, dx\,dy }, $  where $R=[-1,1]\times[0,2]$. Indeed $x\in[-1,1]$ and $y\in[0,2]$.

**My approach:** Since, $|y-x^2|$ is positive everywhere in its domain, therefore,   $\sqrt {  \left| y-{ x }^{ 2 } \right| } $ will exist everywhere in its domain. So, the integral must be the area of the rectangle in the region $R=[-1,1]\times[0,2]$, which is $4$.
Am I right in my approach or am I missing some clue?

Please help me.

Comment: after 144 point you should be able to write correctly a math formula using MathJax ! By the way, what is $R$ ?

Comment: @Surb R has been mentioned in the question. And, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: What does mean $[-1,1;0,2]$

Comment: @Surb It means x ∈ [-1,1] and y ∈ [0,2]

Comment: Usually, this is denoted by $[-1,1]\times [0,2]$.

Comment: btw, is there a square root in the integral?

Comment: The area of rectangular is $$\iint_R { \color{red}{1}dxdy }=4 $$ and as such you miss the structure of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some clue. In particular, you did not use any property of $\sqrt{|y-x^2|}$ besides its existence.

Hint: Consider the region where $y\geq x^2$ and $x^2 \geq y$ separately. Drawing the rectangle and the curve might help you.

Edit:

$$\int\int_R \sqrt{|y-x^2|}dxdy=\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{x^2}\sqrt{x^2-y}dydx+\int_{-1}^1\int_{x^2}^{2}\sqrt{y-x^2}dydx$$

Comment: I tried doing the same, but the region made by y≥x^2 and  x^2≥y is making a rectangle according to me.

Comment: Thank You very much. That proves helpful

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, the double integral asked is equal to the volume of a solid whose base is ${R}$ and the height varies according to $f(x,y)=|y-x^2|$.

Since the region is just rectangular (using Fubini's theorem I think), $$\iint_{R} \left|y-x^2\right| d{R}=\int_0^2\int_{-1}^1 \left|y-x^2\right| dxdy.$$

Comment: @All: This answer was probably posted during a period, when the square root sign was missing from the integrand due to an error in an earlier edit (in the original version the surd -character was kinda small, and easy to miss).